# Export Word document as PDF using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I tried to export a Word document as PDF, from an Excel macro.

The error

> Named argument not found

pops up and highlights `Type:=`.

```vb
Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim wdCell As Word.cell

With wdDoc
    saveLocation = "https://orgindustrie-my.sharepoint.com/personal/different_person_org_com/Documents/folder/subfolder"
      .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
      Filename:=saveLocation & "/" & "File" & Range("G1").Value & ".pdf"
    .Save
    .Close
End With
```

Comment: You're confusing the Excel method `.ExportAsFixedFormat` with the [Word method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.exportasfixedformat). The Word method has no `Type` or `Filename` parameters. Instead it has `ExportFormat` and `OutputFileName` parameters.

Comment: `ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF`   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.exportasfixedformat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're conflating the Excel method [`Workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.exportasfixedformat) and the Word method [`Document.ExportAsFixedFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.exportasfixedformat).

For Word:

> ### Parameters
>
> | Name | Required/Optional | Data Type | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | *OutputFileName* | Required | String | The path and file name of the new PDF or XPS file. |
> | *ExportFormat* | Required | [WdExportFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdexportformat) | Specifies either PDF or XPS format. |

So:

```
    .ExportAsFixedFormat ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
        OutputFileName:=saveLocation & "/" & "File" & Range("G1").Value & ".pdf"
```